# Shell to Python troubles

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu-10.10

```
    if ! ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -v -i tmux | grep "theserver.jar" > /dev/null; then
        echo "Server failed to start!"
    else
        echo "Server successfully started!"
    fi
```

How can i make this with python, please?
I can't figure out how to do it. Please, help :(
Can i use os.system?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you *try* using os.system (yes, you can).

Comment: Shall i try os.system? I haven't tried anything, since i don't know what to ry.

Comment: os.system("if ! ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -v -i tmux | grep 'theserver.jar' > /dev/null; then
        echo 'Server failed to start!'
    else
        echo 'Server successfully started!'
    fi")

Answer (score 2):

You can shell out with the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module and run arbitrary shell commands, but you may want to consider using something like the [PSI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PSI) or [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) modules.

They are non-standard so you will have to download and install them, but they will be much more robust and resistant to errors.  (Remember that `ps` output formats can change across different platforms).  Here is an example psutil implementation that does more or less what you're trying to do.  Obviously swap `'Python'` with `'theserver.jar'` or use `p.exe` or `p.cmdline` if you need to inspect more than just the name.

```
import psutil

def find_processes_by_name(name):
  for p in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
      if p.name == name:
        yield p.pid
    except psutil.error.AccessDenied as e:
      pass

  raise StopIteration

print "Python processes:"
for pid in find_processes_by_name('Python'):
  print '\t', pid
```

Answer (score 1):

Say I want to find out if I am on a server running sshd(just a replacement for the jar file in your example)

```
import os

command=" ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -v -i tmux | grep sshd"

result = os.WEXITSTATUS(os.system(command))

if os.WEXITSTATUS(os.system(command)):
  print "Server failed to start!"
else:
  print "Server successfully started!"
```

You need the WEXITSTATUS to fix the return value from the os.system call. For your use just replace sshd with theserver.jar